# Normalize 2D array given mean and std value

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, normalization

l have a dataset called `2d_data` which has a **dimension=(44500,224,224)** such that **44500** is the number of sample.

l would like to normalize this data set using the following mean and std values :

`mean=0.485` and `std=0.229`

How can l do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Normalization is: (X - Mean) / Deviation

So do just that: `(2d_data - mean) / std`